# Validation for parent_id in yii2

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hi I have a problem in validation, I’m using yii2 Advanced application.

I have a parent_id while creating menu i give menu name and provide that weather this menu is parent menu or not, if parent menu check-box is checked if not the then from Drop-down a menu will be selected.

The problem is if make this parent id as required in model under rules, then in the view both the check-box and drop-down is will validate and both will show required. But I want only any one of it. If i don’t give it as required then validation itself is not happening. See the Below Image.
[image: In this both check-box and drop-down is required.]

Here is my active form..

```
   <?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->checkbox(array( 
    'id'=>'new', 
    'value'=>'0',
    'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'), 
    'disabled'=>false 
    )); ?>

<div class="select" id="select"> 
<?= $form->field($model,'parent_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
'data' => $menu,
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a Menu name ...'],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
],
]); ?>
</div>
```

I want the validation to be happen if both of them have been left blank. Kindly tell me any solution.

Answer (score 1):

First and for a cleaner code if I did correctly understand your requirement I would suggest introducing a new virtual attribute to your **model** class instead of 2 fields assigning different values to the same attribute:

```
$form->field($model,'is_parent')->checkbox(...) // don't do 'value'=>'0' here. it will be auto mapped to model virtual attribute.
$form->field($model,'parent_id')->widget(...)
/*
 instead of :
   $form->field($model,'parent_id')->checkbox(...) // parent_id is 1 or 0 here
   $form->field($model,'parent_id')->widget(...)
*/
```

Then apply a [Conditional Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation) into your **model** rules using the [when](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail) property:

```
public $is_parent;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['is_parent', 'boolean'],
        // 'parent_id' is required only if the checkbox is not checked
        ['parent_id', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
            return !$model->is_parent;
        }],
    ];
}
```

**Note:** The linked docs also says:

> If you also need to support client-side conditional validation, you
>   should configure the whenClient property which takes a string
>   representing a JavaScript function whose return value determines
>   whether to apply the rule or not.

Which is expected as Client Validation script is based on your initial rules. so you have 2 options. Either you completely disable it in your ActiveForm and use Ajax Validation instead:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    ...
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true
]); ?>
```

Or the other option is to add the missing client related script to your rules as shown in docs, which may look like the following in your case:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['is_parent', 'boolean'],

        ['parent_id', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
            return !$model->is_parent;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            return !$('#menu-is_parent').val();
        }"],
    ];
}
```

- *Note here that I did expect your [formName()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName()-detail) to return `'menu'`. By default it returns the model class name. you can also use your browser's dev tools to inspect the checkbox input and see what `id` is assignet to it by Yii.*

Finally if a specific `parent_id` value should be set when the checkbox is checked you may use [beforeSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail) or [afterValidate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#afterValidate()-detail) to manually set it to any value you need like maybe:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($this->is_parent) $this->parent_id = $someModel->id;
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: I Tried your suggestion, Its not working, Even if I check the checkbox the parent_id is validating and it is required.

Comment: check the update. I guess you have enableClientValidation set to true as it is the case by default. if it is the case, you'll need to either use ajax validation instead or adding related WhenClient code to your rules.

Comment: so did it work ? did you try what I did add to the answer as a note section ?

Comment: then something else should be wrong as I did try the code before my last update. did you remove the old `'parent_id'` related rule and leaving only the conditional one ? did you try disabling client code ? is there something else forcing `$model->is_parent` to hold a different value ? try to fake validation manually into a different action like `$model = new Menu();$model->load(['menu'=>['parent_id'=>'','is_parent'=>1]]);$model->validate();print_r($model->errors);` and see what it gives. that should help debugging the app. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use custom validation for this purpose:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['field1', function ($attribute, $params) {
                    // if (...) 
                    $this->addError($attribute, 'Must field1 or field2 be set');
                }
            }],
        ];
    }
```